# illegal start of Statement (Simon Says, Java)

Tags: java

I have to program a game logic for Simon says. Here is the error i always get:

Simon_says.java:28:5: error: illegal start of Statement

Here's the Program:

```
public class Simon_says {
  private int Red = 0;

  private int Green = 1;

  private int Yellow = 2;

  private int Blue = 3;

  private int [] simonArray  = new int[4];

  private int [] playerArray = new int[4];

  private int z = new String[4];

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] simonArraylist = {0,1,2,3};

    int [] playerArraylist = {0,1,2,3};

    int z = simonArraylist;

    System.out.println ("Game Over"); 

  }
  public static int getRandom(int[] simonArraylist) {

    int rnd = new Random().nextInt(array.length);

    return array[rnd];
  }

    public static void main (int[] args){
 {

    for (i=0;i!=playerArraylist;i++)
    }
   }
}
```

I also appreciate some suggestions to improve the program.

Comment: Why do you have two `main`? and where is the opening brackets for the class?

Comment: What line is line 28?

Comment: I like this line: `private int z = new String[4];`  ;-)

Comment: You might want to use an IDE

Comment: Why would you want to declare a variable `int`, then initialize it with a `new String[4]`, then try to to do `int z = simonArraylist` where the right operand is an `int[]`? nothing makes sense here, the types are wrong. Also inside `main()` you're re-declaring your variables and not using your `private ..` ones from the class-instance.

Answer (score 0):

Java compiler is very intelligent, it give you the line number and column number.

Use a development KIT like Eclipe, IntelliJ etc.

There are many compile time error with your code.

1. private int z = new String[4]; //cannot convert from String[] to int i.e. z
2. int z = simonArraylist; //cannot convert from int[] i.e simonArraylist to //int i.e. z
3. In method getRandom, you are using array which is not defined.

and many more.